# php function array_key_exists and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to use a regular expression with the php function `array_key_exists()`?

For example:

```
$exp = "my regex";  
array_key_exists($exp, $array);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can extract the array keys using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and then use [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) on that array:

```
function preg_array_key_exists($pattern, $array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);    
    return (int) preg_grep($pattern,$keys);
}
```

.

```
$arr = array("abc"=>12,"dec"=>34,"fgh"=>56);

var_dump(preg_array_key_exists('/c$/',$arr)); // check if a key ends in 'c'.
var_dump(preg_array_key_exists('/x$/',$arr)); // check if a key ends in 'x'.

function preg_array_key_exists($pattern, $array) {
    // extract the keys.
    $keys = array_keys($array);    

    // convert the preg_grep() returned array to int..and return.
    // the ret value of preg_grep() will be an array of values
    // that match the pattern.
    return (int) preg_grep($pattern,$keys);
}
```

Output:

```
$php a.php
int(1)
int(0)
```

Comment: instead of flipping you can use array_keys()

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid not.  You can iterate the array keys and perform matches on those:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach ($keys as $key)
  if (preg_match($exp, $key) == 1)
    return $array[$key];
```

Comment: or just if(preg_match(...)) in the case of multiple result occurencies.

Comment: @zerkms: `preg_match()` only matches the first occurrence of the pattern. Therefore it can only return `0` or `1`. Please see http://php.net/preg_match