# preg_match part of an array key value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to check if the value of a given key exists in an array (inside a foreach loop).

For some reason it doesn't really work as expected.

The idea is that I already know the name of the key, but only know part of the correlating value for the key.

I'm trying to do something like this, assuming that I know the key is "exampleKeyName" and its value may or may-not contain "matchValue":

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
  if (stripos($array["exampleKeyName"], 'matchValue') !== false) { echo "matched"; }
}
```

This returns "illegal string offset".

However, if I do this it works:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
  if (stripos($value, 'matchValue') !== false) { echo "matched"; }
}
```

The problem here is that I want to be more specific with the query, and only check if the key is "exampleKeyName".

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is : You want to know if a regex pattern matches `$array['exampleKeyName']` ?

Comment: No match the value of that key

Comment: Why you need to do this check inside `foreach` loop?

Comment: @hindmost because the array is inside another array

Comment: Do you want it with preg_match()

Comment: the first code doesn't make sense since none of `foreach` parameters (`$key`, `$value`) is used in its iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stripos](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.stripos.php) to check the array value contains in a matching string like this way:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
  if (stripos($array[$key], 'matchValue') !== false) { echo "matched"; }
}
```

Comment: @user3143218. Great to hear that its worked. Have a nice time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if your regex pattern matches a specific value in your array :

```
if(preg_match("/^yourpattern$/",$myArray["exampleKeyName"])>0) {
    // The value of $myArray["exampleKeyName"] is matched by the regex
}
```

If you check if the regex matches a key :

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value):
    if(preg_match("/^yourpattern$/",$key)>0) {
        // $key is matched by the regex
    }
endforeach;
```

I hope it helps !

edit : bad english

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off, and there are a few ways of doing this.

In your example code you weren't checking the `key` but the `value` in both cases. When doing a `for` loop like in your second code example you have to change your `if` statement like so to check against the `key`:

```
if (stripos($key, 'matchValue') !== false) { echo "matched"; }
```

Since I don't know what the application of this is I'll just tell you a few other ways of achieving this and perhaps they will also help simplify the code.

php has a helper function called [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) that checks if the given key or index exists in the array. The result is a boolean value. If you just need to know if the array contains an index or key that is another way of doing this. That would look like this:

```
if( array_key_exists('matchValue', $array) ) { 
    print('Key exists');
} else {
    print('No key found');
}
```

There is a good [Stack Overflow posting about using preg_grep for regex searching of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471120/php-function-array-key-exists-and-regular-expressions) keys that may also be helpful if you need to use regular expressions for this.