# Check if object contains an property matching a string

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 [type] => 5 [color_a] => 57 [color_b] => 3 [date] => 2 )
```

How to check if the object has attributes that CONTAIN the string "color" ?

I tried with array_diff_key and array_filter but i cannot use ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY because it runs on PHP 5.4.

No loops if possible :)

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471120/php-function-array-key-exists-and-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just cast the object to an array and search with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) in the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Then I simply flip the array back with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php))

```
$result = array_flip(preg_grep("/\bcolor/", array_keys((array)$o)));
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array ( [color_a] => 2 [color_b] => 3 )
```

And if you just want to use it to check for TRUE or FALSE like with in_array() you don't need to flip it back and you can simply use it like this:

```
if(preg_grep("/\bcolor/", array_keys((array)$o)))
    echo "match";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isKeyExists($key,$array){
    $arr = preg_grep('/.*'.$key.'.*/',array_keys($array));
    if(count($arr)){
        return true;
    }  
    return false;
}
$arr = Array('id'=>'11','type'=>5,'color_a'=>57,'color_b'=>3,'date'=>2);
isKeyExists('color_',$arr); // return boolean if exists or not
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex solution:

```
    $std          = new StdClass();
    $std->id      = 11;
    $std->type    = 5;
    $std->color_a = 57;
    $std->color_b = 3;
    $std->date    = 2;

    $result    = array();
    $searchFor = 'color';

    array_map(function($value) use(&$result, $searchFor){

        if(strpos($value, $searchFor) !== false){
            $result[] = $value;
        }

    }, array_keys((array)$std));

    var_dump(count($result));
```