# Find a word inside a string

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
[
  "customer" => 2325
  "product1" => 3,
  "product4" => 1,
  "product12" => 2
]
```

And I want to run a for-loop to find the keys that contain the word *product* and also get the number after the word. Is there any php function to find specific words inside a string?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471120/php-function-array-key-exists-and-regular-expressions

Comment: `strpos` is this function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: @feniixx you could probably refactor the code that produces this array to make this an lot easier task

Answer (score 0):

You could likely loop through your array while using `stristr`:

```
foreach($arr as $item => $val) { 
    $res[] = stristr($item, 'product');
    $int[] = filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
print_r(array_filter($res)); // output keys with substring 'product'
print_r(array_filter($int)); // output integers from product key substring
```

This would allow you to collect any keys that contain the sub-string 'product'. From there you could also capture any integers associated with that key.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => product1
    [2] => product4
    [3] => product12
)
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 12
)
```